# How can I create a full page preloader?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a preloader that appears with loading bars plus white background and then fades out with the white background after 4 seconds.

The preloader should be at the center. Right now it doesn't center the preloader plus the fading effect is not smooth.

Here's my HTML:

```js
const loaderWrapper = document.querySelector('.loaderWrapper');

const fadeEffect = setInterval(() => {
  if (!loaderWrapper.style.opacity) {
    loaderWrapper.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  if (loaderWrapper.style.opacity > 0) {
    loaderWrapper.style.opacity -= 0.1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(fadeEffect);
  }
}, 300);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: rgb(199, 199, 199);
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.loaderWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.loader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.loader .bar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 2px;
  animation: bar 1s infinite linear;
}

.loader .bar:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.loader .bar:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

.loader .bar:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes bar {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(10) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loaderWrapper">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <h1>This is our page title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

How can I make the loading bar icons on the center with the white background and then have a smooth fading out effect after four seconds?

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqd0xfsk/1/

Comment: Checkout my answer, it doesn't use any javascript and achieves what you really want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You don't really need the Javascript here. It can be achieved without using any javascript!

So I removed javascript from the javascript code and added a CSS animation as follows to the `.loaderWrapper` and added CSS for centering the elements, like this:

```css
@keyframes fadeLoader {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.loaderWrapper {
  .
  .
  .
  pointer-events: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: fadeLoader 0.6s 4s ease forwards;
}
```

Code for centering elements vertically and horizontally:

```css
.loaderWrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Animation code:

```css
.loaderWrapper {
  animation: fadeLoader 0.6s 4s ease forwards;
}
```

- `fadLoader`: Animation name
- `0.6s`: Animation Duration
- `4s`: Animation delay
- `ease`: Animation function
- `forwards`: Execute animation only once
  Try to run this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #898989;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.loaderWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: fadeLoader 0.6s 4s ease forwards;
}

.loader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 999;
}
.loader .bar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 2px;
  animation: bar 1s infinite linear;
}
.loader .bar:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.loader .bar:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
.loader .bar:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes bar {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(10) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeLoader {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Iko Preloader</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loaderWrapper">
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>
    </div>

      <div id="content">
        <h1>This is our page title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>

      <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or see it in the JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vxju64sc/2/

Comment: This looks good. Is there anyway i could add a delay like 2-3 seconds before doing the fading effect?

Comment: There is `4s` delay already added in the animation, if you want to increase or decrease the value you can do so

Comment: Tried but it seems that the delay is not working. `  animation: fadeLoader 0.6s 10s ease forwards;`

Comment: added that but it did not the delay the animation before it fires.

Comment: The animation I'm talking about is the fading effect which will have 4s delay, if you use 10s then it will have 10s delay. Here delay means the fading animation will take place after delay duration is passed, so fading effect will take place after 4s or 10s (in your case)

Comment: If you want fading to last longer, then increase 0.6s to something else, fading will take more time to animate

Comment: Make sure to add something like `loaderWrapper.addEventListener("animationend", () => loaderWrapper.remove())` to your JS. Otherwise you can't interact with the main content. Or alternatively set `.loaderWrapper { pointer-events: none; }` in your CSS (but then you can click through the loader).

Comment: @JosefWittmann Yes right, thanks for mentioning this! Make sure you add this, I'll update my answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

Just **Change the following CSS** and it will **fix your issue**.

```
.loaderWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.loader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  z-index: 999;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some edits to your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wxky2t4m/9/

The main part is using the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API) for **smooth transitions** - and most important to hide the overlay once it's finished (to **allow interacting with the main content**).
You could also use CSS transitions, but I don't know if you get a `finish` event there.

```js
const loaderWrapper = document.querySelector('.loaderWrapper');

const fade = loaderWrapper.animate([
    { opacity: 1 },
    { opacity: 0 },
  ], {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: "ease-in"
  }
)

// Remove the element to allow clicking the main content.
fade.addEventListener("finish", () => loaderWrapper.style.display = "none")
```

But there were minor things in the CSS regarding flexbox, which center your bars.

You could also use jQuery, if you want: https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: This looks good but I have one comment. How can I make it look appear in full capacity for 2 seconds before start the fading effect?

Comment: Use `delay: 2000` in the `animate(...)` options. Have a look at the docs here (the names are the same as in CSS): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS animation on the loader as well as on the bars and that will do the timing for you - if you make it 5sec duration and the first 80% it doesn't do anything and then it begins to fade. You can also set your bars to go up and down for 5 iterations so they will stop animating after they have faded.

The centering is achieved with a little more CSS in the loader.

No setInterval/JS needed so it's smoother.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: rgb(199, 199, 199);
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.loaderWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
  animation: loader 5s 1 linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 999;
}
.loader .bar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 2px;
  animation: bar 1s 5 linear;
}
.loader .bar:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.loader .bar:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
.loader .bar:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes loader {
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bar {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(10) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loaderWrapper">
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
</div>

  <div id="content">
    <h1>This is our page title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
```